# g++ throwing file not recognized: File format not recognized error

Tags: linux, g++, libpq

getting following error with the command `g++ -o test -L . -l pq`

```
libpq.so: file not recognized: File format not recognized

#file libpq.so
libpq.so: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), not stripped
```

gcc version 4.1.2 20070115 (SUSE Linux)

I am getting the same error if I try to use `-l dbodbc` instead of `-l pq`.

Note that `test.c` is a simple hello world program.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I bet you're trying to compile this with a 32-bit version of G++.

Comment: which g++ shows "/usr/bin/g++" and file on /usr/bin/g++ shows "/usr/bin/g++: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), for GNU/Linux 2.6.4, dynamically linked (uses shared libs), stripped". So I think this makes it clear that g++ is 64 bit

Comment: Don't call your program `test` it is the name of a shell builtin. And what does the commands `file`, `nm -D`, and `objdump -x` say about your `libpq.so` ?

Comment: file libpq.so
libpq.so: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), not stripped

Comment: objdump -x libpq.so
objdump: libpq.so: File format not recognized

Comment: objdump is throwing this error only in one particular linux box. If I copy the same .so to a different box, objdump is showing correct info. The issue is with machine or the compiler version?

Answer (score 7):

`file /usr/bin/g++` tells you that `g++` itself is a 64-bit executable, i.e. it runs on a 64-bit machine, it *doesn't* tell you that g++ can *compile* 64-bit code (it's very unlikely but it *could* be a cross compiler for a completely different processor!) Use `g++ -v` or `g++ -dumpmachine` to find out what target it generates executables for.

G++ doesn't actually use that library, it just passes the `-l` option to the linker, so the error is coming from the linker, `ld`

If `ld` and `objdump` are both saying they can't recognize the library but the same file is fine on a different machine, I would try updating or reinstalling the `binutils` package, which provides both `ld` and `objdump`.

You might have a 32-bit `binutils` installed, so its `ld` and `objdump` wouldn't understand the x86_64 library.  Ensure you have the 64-bit (i.e. x86_64) binutils RPM installed.